# Magento2 Split Order Functionality

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order, order-splitting

I am using b2b marketplace extension in my website. I need to split orders based on vendor id. I got one split order module https://github.com/magestat/magento2-split-order , which is splitting orders based on product attribute. But it is not caluculating shipping , totals , subtotals correctly. If it is a single product from a vendor then everything is working fine. If customer added 5 products to cart and 3 of them belongs to one vendor and 2 of them belongs to another vendor then total amount caluculation is showing wrong. Can anybody help me on this?

i just tested with product weight attribute even though grand total is displaying one last item only

Comment: Do you mean that the plugin has a bug or you have a distinct requirement, so you need advice in customising the module?

Comment: The module has a bug , I already mentioned in github issues. If any body helps me to fix this issue i posted it here.